# MongoDb Structure Recommendation

Tags: mongodb, memory, memory-management, database

I need to store the items owned by a user.

I'm currently using a structure like:

```
...
inventory:{
    itemId1:2,
    myOtherItem:120,
    something:1
},
...
```

I am considering switching to a structure like:

```
...
inventory:[
    {id:"itemId1",amount:2},
    {id:"myOtherItem",amount:120},
    {id:"something",amount:1}
],
...
```

Is the second way the recommended way to store data? If so, is there any advantage over the first way?

Memory storage is limited. Will use the second way take much more storage? Does MongoDb store "id" and "amount" for every element in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Yes and Yes are the short answers. Yes change it. There are many reasons why.

First point, total inventory:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$inventory" },
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$inventory.id",
       "amount": { "$sum": "$amount" }
    }}
])
```

Or across documents. Painful to do with the existing structure since any server processing would require JavaScript execution that is not as efficient.

Second, Find a document where one of your "inventory" items has an amount more than 10. Painful JavaScript processing without an index by what you have, or simple in the second form:

```js
db.collection.find({ "inventory.amount": { "$gt": 10 } })
```

Will it take up more space, yes it will take a "little" more space to store but the benefits outweigh this. It's really not that much of a difference to be worried about.

It's a better and more consistent way to store things and maps consistently to any object in code without relying on "hash/map" key stores for a particular field.

So since it "plays nice" with various MongoDB methods and allows things to be indexed, then Yes it's recommended for that. Yes there are advantages such as those mentioned. And Yes as the saying goes "Nothing is free", so there would be a storage impact but it is nearly negligible. But that's the price for better options.